# No gain from a few pthreads on AMD processor?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

So, I just got a new 16-core server with AMD 6212 processors. I have code that I've run on a variety of Intel processors as well. It uses locked queues to distribute work to pthreads, which then write the work back to shared memory with locks on the writes as well. I'm primarily compute bound.

On Intel processors, as I increase the number of threads, my performance immediately increases. Going from 1 to 2 threads nearly doubles performance.

With the same code on the AMD processors, I get no gain (a slight slowdown) with even 4 threads. But, when I use 128 threads, I see a 6x speedup.

Does anyone have an idea what that might be happening?

As for the OS specs, if I type:

```
cat /proc/version
```

I get:

```
Linux version 2.6.32-5-amd64 (Debian 2.6.32-39) (dannf@debian.org) (gcc version 4.3.5 (Debian 4.3.5-4) ) #1 SMP Thu Nov 3 03:41:26 UTC 2011
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this hasn't been 100% resolved yet, but it appears that the problem was related to memory access. The code has no dynamic memory allocation during most of the run, but threads were allocating about 100 small chunks of memory on the heap when they started up. In small sample versions of the program I was able to eliminate the bottlenecks by allocating the memory for each thread on the stack instead of the heap.

Without looking too deeply into architecture issues it appears that the allocated memory might have gotten interleaved so that the different threads were sharing the same memory, thus destroying parallel performance.

Comment: To follow up further, the remaining issues were caused by access to global variables, which didn't slow things down on the Intel side, but had a huge negative impact on the AMD side. Switching to Ubuntu seemed to help as well.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that the Linux scheduler didn't put your threads on separate cores.

The Linux scheduler tries *very hard* to keep tasks on the CPU they last used, so that the cache has the best chance of containing relevant and useful data or instructions. I've found that it does not, in fact, rebalance. (I know, I've even seen code that claims to do the re-balancing, but I've spotted CPU-intensive workloads all running on the same sibling before without ever moving to another core.)

Does your code use `taskset(1)`, `sched_setaffinity(2)` or the `cpuset(7)` mechanism to *manually* spread the compute-intensive tasks around to all processors? If not, I suggest trying `taskset(1)` by hand first to see if your throughput improves, and including `sched_setaffinity(2)` calls into your program if you see the improvements you expect.

Comment: So, this is strange. When I run with 4 threads I see no speedup, but 400% utilization in `top`. When I use something like `taskset 0x3 ./myprogram -threads 4` I see a 1.5x speedup.

Comment: The scheduler might pick different cores each execution; once your program is running, use `taskset -p <pid0> -c 0`, `taskset -p <pid1> -c 1`, `taskset -p <pid2> -c 2`, etc. to force each thread to a different core.

Comment: That gives about a 1.2x speedup versus 1.5x for just forcing the processors onto two cores.

Comment: Wow. Given how you described the Intel variant, I expected that to make all the difference in the world. Note that the Intel chips have siblings numbered consecutively -- does AMD do something similar? If so, try `0`, `2`, `4`, `6` to spread them among actual cores rather than hyperthread siblings.

Comment: The AMD processors show up as 0..15, so it doesn't appear that hyper-threading is involved. The same code on a dual-core i7 with hyper-threading sees a 1.8x speedup with 2 threads and a 2.3x speedup with 4 threads.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty disappointing, I'd hope a 16 core chip could do much better with more threads. I hope you've got an AMD contact who can help you out...